# В многопоточном tcp клиент - серверном приложении проскакивают битые сообщения

Tags: c#, многопоточность, сервер, tcp, client

При многопоточной работе клиента и сервера через TpcClient и и записи данных через NetworkStream при работе в 100 потоком через ~ минут 30 или 1000 потоков и минут 10 после куче валидных сообщений проскакивает битое сообщение склееное из нескольких и между ними китайские иероглифы. На большом количестве потоков проверяю чтобы найти баги, этот баг не могу приложить ума как исправить, может есть какие то практики для работы TCP которые это решают эту проблему?
Отправляю пакеты так:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sendData);
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Получаю так:

```
byte[] data = new byte[64];
int bytes;
do
{
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    if (bytes != 0)
    {
        string receivingData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        BufferReceiver.Append(receivingData);
    }
}
while (stream.DataAvailable);
if (bytes == 0) break;
```

Comment: Стандартная ошибка. Метод `stream.Read` может прочитать любое количество байтов, например, 5. Далее, что получится в `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` из этих пяти байтов? Символы utf-16 состоят из 2 или 4 байт. Решение: читайте все данные полностью в буфер и лишь затем преобразовывайте в строку.

Comment: В жизни бы не догадался, спасибо, буду исправлять!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как указали в комментарии, `stream.Read` может вернуть ровное или меньшее количество байт, чем запрашиваемый размер буфера.

Решить можно как-то так (буфер побольше можно сделать):

```
Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[512];
int bytesReceived = 0;
MemoryStream ms = new(buffer.Length);
while ((bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    ms.Write(buffer[..bytesReceived]);
}
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer().AsSpan()[..ms.Length]);
```

Очень рекомендую вместо Unicode использовать UTF-8 для передачи данных.

Comment: Спасибо, но уже решил вопрос благодаря комментарию, идея по поводу использования stackalloc хороша, добавлю себе.

Comment: @Apocryph0n есть ещё `ArrayPool<T>`, тоже полезная штука